# How to split an address in TALEND based on UPPER CASE values?

Tags: talend

I want to split the below address from single column to multiple columns using talend.

**Input**

|ADDRESS|

|15 St. Patrick Rd NORTH WEST LONDON|

**Expected Output**

|ADDRESS_LINE1 | ADDRESS_LINE2 |

|15 St. Patrick Rd |   NORTH WEST LONDON |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these two following regex expressions allow to split your input ADDRESS as you specified :

ADDRESS_LINE1 = StringHandling.TRIM(
input.ADDRESS.replaceAll("^(.+?)(([A-Z]{2,}\\s*?)+)$", "$1")
)
;

ADDRESS_LINE2 = StringHandling.TRIM(
input.ADDRESS.replaceAll("^(.+?)(([A-Z]{2,}\\s*?)+)$", "$2")
)
;
[image: TMAP]

[image: result]

Comment: This worked perfectly. However for me initially it threw an error as

"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \f \" \' \ )"  ... 


So adding an another "\" before "\s" had worked then ...

Comment: Glad to see I could help.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the regex bit more in detail ?